# How do I copy built artifact to a directory on remote Windows server in maven deploy phase?

Tags: java, maven-2, build, automated-deploy

could someone provide working example (full maven plugin configuration) how to copy built jar file to a specific server(s) at the time of deploy phase?

I have tried to look at wagon plugin, but it is hugely undocumented and I was not able to set it up. The build produces standard jar that is being deployed to Nexus, but I need to put the jar also to the test server automatically over local network (\someserver\testapp\bin).

I will be grateful for any hints.

Thank you

Answer (score 8):

Actually I have found a different way:
Dependency plugin!

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <id>copy-to-ebs</id>
      <phase>deploy</phase>
      <goals>
          <goal>copy</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <artifactItems>
          <artifactItem>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>${project.artifactId}</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
            <type>${project.packaging}</type>
          </artifactItem>
        </artifactItems>
        <outputDirectory>\\someserver\somedirectory</outputDirectory>
        <stripVersion>true</stripVersion>                    
      </configuration>
    </execution>                        
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

It also takes windows path like \\resource.

Note that \\someserver\somedirectory works from windows client only.

Comment: How to setup credentials in this case?

Comment: How to do it under linux?

Comment: Right now im using mounted path: /run/user/1000/gvfs/smb-share:server=SERVER_NAME,share=SHARED_FOLDER_NAME

Answer (score 1):

I don't have a working example but the ["Maven Assembly Plugin"](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-assembly-plugin/assembly.html) should do the job. You can configure it to run automatically in the deploy phase.
When you write your own assembly descriptor you can specify a path where the assembly should be written to. I think maven shouldn't care about whether it's a local or remote path.